# Delphi Seattle cannot reference default FMX class

Tags: android, ios, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

While trying to implement [Notifications](http://docwiki.appmethod.com/appmethod/1.13/topics/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_the_Notification_Center_(iOS_and_Android)) at my project, Delphi Seattle can't reference `FMX.Notification` properly.

This is what I get:

> [DCC Fatal Error] UnitMain.pas(27): F2613 Unit 'FMX.Notification' not found.

And then it makes an automatically reference to `System.Notification`, however it crashes my Android app when trying to use a object from this class.

How can I correctly implement Notifications on Delphi Seattle?

*Note: It must run on both `iOS` and `Android`.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Embarcadero's official Seattle changes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/What's_New):

The FMX.Notification unit has been replaced by `System.Notification`.

The `TNotificationCenter` component now supports Windows 8 and later Windows versions. This component has also undergone some minor changes:

- It provides a Loaded property to check whether the notification center is ready to use or not.
- The type of `ApplicationIconBadgeNumber` has changed from Word to Integer.
- Its `Supported` method is no longer necessary and has been removed.

The `TBaseNotificationCenter` class has replaced the `IFMXNotificationCenter` interface. Classes that used to implement the `IFMXNotificationCenter` interface must become subclasses of `TBaseNotificationCenter` and implement the virtual abstract methods of their parent class.

---

Hereby how I figured out to display notifications now:

```
procedure TForm_Master.showNotification(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyNotification: TNotification;
begin

    MyNotification := NotificationCenter1.CreateNotification;

    try
      MyNotification.Name := 'NotificationName';
      MyNotification.AlertBody :=
        'Here goes your message';
      MyNotification.FireDate := Now;
      // Send notification to the notification center
      NotificationCenter1.ScheduleNotification(MyNotification);
    finally
      MyNotification.Free;
    end;

  end;
```